# C++: Overload a member's constructor function with keyword operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

In the Halide's source code, I read this line of code:

```
operator halide_type_t() const { return type; }
```

in the definition of the a class named `Type`, and it contains a member `type` which is `halide_type_t` struct.

I am a little confused about the `operator` overloading, and how should I use the new function `halide_type_t()`?

Comment: See [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: And it could be used like `Type t; halide_type_t htt = t;` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the code below:

```
struct number{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
    operator float() { return numerator*1.0 / denominator }

}
void main(){
    number n;
    n.numerator = 3;
    n.denominator = 4;
    float value = n; // here the user-defined conversion occurs
    std::cout << value; // 0.75
}
```

In this case, user-defined conversion takes place. Whenever an object of number is
assigned to a float value, the conversion takes place and the value is returned.
In your case, when an object of class Type is assigned to struct halide_type_t,
ie

```
  Type t1;
  halide_type_t t = t1;
```

the value of t1.type is assigned to t.
Hope it helps! :)